# Why doesn't this properly color the substring in my UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, nsattributedstring

I want a particular substring to be yellow.  I don't want to break it up into multiple UILabels since that would make localizing the layout a nightmare.  So I do this:

```
    NSMutableAttributedString* instructions = [[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.o_instructionsLabel.text] autorelease];
    NSRange range = [instructions.string rangeOfString:@"FOOBARBAZ"];
    if (range.length > 0)
    {
        [instructions addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor yellowColor] range:range];
        self.o_instructionsLabel.attributedText = instructions;
    }
```

However, the whole of the text in the label remains white. This seems to be how all the examples do it, I verified the range is correct, and when I dump the `instructions` object, I see the attributes inline where I guess they should be.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: one first thought, although not possible i guess, is that you use a custom UILabel class and you have added custom code in (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect method so it ignores attributed stuff

Comment: your code looks ok, just tested it on sample project and it works perfectly. in which moment this code is executed?

Comment: On closer inspection, you are correct apostolos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was custom code in `drawTextInRect:` was ignoring the attributed string.